# Run-Time Error 13

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

Not having a great day on the programming front. I cannot see why VBA cannot do the following sum.

Can you please assist.

I have 2 fields in a userform both with a date. All I want is to subtract them to work out the days in between

I have tried 2 variations of this.

```
ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = TxtRecDate.Value - TxtDOD.Value
ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = CInt(TxtRecDate.Value) - CInt(TxtDOD.Value)
```

Both are giving me run-time error 13 mismatch.

Can you please help?

Thanks,

Comment: where is your code placed ? in a User_Form ? or regular Module ? you need to add `Me.` or the `UserFromName.` before the `TxtRecDate` and `TxtDOD.Value`

Comment: Hi, it is placed in a userform. Sorry I had tried with Me.TxtRecDate.Value - Me.TxtDOD.Value but this does not work either. I receive the same error,

Comment: do you have there dates ? which are actualy stored as Text ?

Comment: The dates are being entered into the userform. For example today - yesterday should = 1. In the fields they are being entered they are formatted as Format(Me.txtRecdate.value, "DD/MM/YYYY") and same for me.txtdod.value

Comment: Try `ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = CDbl(Me.TxtRecDate.Value) - CDbl(Me.TxtDOD.Value)`

Comment: Unfortunately this still yields the same error.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print TypeName(TxtRecDate.Value ) & ", " & TypeName(TxtDOD.Value)` What do you get?

Comment: Use `CDate`: `ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = CDate(Me.TxtRecDate.Value) - CDate(Me.TxtDOD.Value)`

Comment: Hi John, for this one I appear to be receiving runtime error 424. There are no mispellings and I cannot see an object missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `text` in the textboxes to `date`:

```
    ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = DateValue(TxtRecDate.Value) - DateValue(TxtDOD.Value)
```

Note this will cause `Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch` if the text doesn't represent a date correctly. You can handle this by testing the textbox values first:

```
    If IsDate(TxtRecDate) And IsDate(TxtDOD) Then
        ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = DateValue(TxtRecDate.Value) - DateValue(TxtDOD.Value)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid dates entered", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test to see if both textboxes contain valid dates.  Then use `DateValue` to convert the String values into Date values.

```
If IsDate(TxtRecDate.Value) And IsDate(TxtDOD.Value) Then

    ws1.Cells(mRow, 28).Value = DateValue(TxtRecDate.Value) - DateValue(TxtDOD.Value)

End If
```